# Stepper motor C Implementation

Tags: c, stepper

Been unsuccessful in finding this answer elsewhere.

Is there a typical way to implement stepper motor, Accel, velocity and speed control in C?

The clock speed doesn't seem quick enough to toggle a step pin each loop. Do people normally use a CTC interrupt and change the timer compare value? I want to move a certain amount of steps at a definable Vel and Accel.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Oppy

Comment: If the CPU clock isn't fast enough then you will have to use an external timer that isn't driven by the clock.  But there is a maximum speed you can step a motor - if you go too fast you just get a buzzing noise.  So try whichever is easiest first - it's the same as any other programming: get it working then optimize it only if it's necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I just had a look at the Melzi stepper motor control board you find in a lot of 3d printers. The step pin from the controller is attached directly to an Atmega1284P. I think I need to try look at what the software is doing...

Comment: The difference between CPU speed and the responses of mechanical equipment like steppers is so one-sided that it is difficult to imagine that any microcontroller ever could be too slow.

Comment: That's not quite what I mean. My main loop is 2ms, if I were to toggle a pin at that rate and the stepper has 200 steps per revolution the stepper can only do 2.5 revolutions per second. If I were to add micro-stepping suddenly it becomes quite slow.

Answer (score 0):

Time ago I wrote a C device driver on an STM8S microcontroller for a 24 VDC Sonceboz stepper motor.

Between the CPU and the motor I put an L6219 stepper motor driver.

The CPU clock was 8 MHz.

I used a hardware timer that every 10 ms fired an interrupt.

Within the interrupt function there was my code that drove the L6219 driver.

The CPU time spent in the interrupt function was less than 20 micro seconds.